# Get table name by foreign key

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I have a two tables in the database. First table has a foreign key to second table.

Can I get second table name by the foreign key from first table?

Comment: Cross-post: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94567/get-table-name-by-foreign-key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
SELECT ct.oid, conname, condeferrable, condeferred, confupdtype, confdeltype, confmatchtype, conkey, confkey, confrelid, nl.nspname as fknsp, cl.relname as fktab, nr.nspname as refnsp, cr.relname as reftab, description, convalidated
      FROM pg_constraint ct
      JOIN pg_class cl ON cl.oid=conrelid
      JOIN pg_namespace nl ON nl.oid=cl.relnamespace
      JOIN pg_class cr ON cr.oid=confrelid
      JOIN pg_namespace nr ON nr.oid=cr.relnamespace
      LEFT OUTER JOIN pg_description des ON (des.objoid=ct.oid AND des.classoid='pg_constraint'::regclass)
     WHERE contype='f' AND ct.conname = 'yourfk_name' -- conrelid = 26941::oid
     ORDER BY conname;
```

Just valorize yourfk_name with your foreign_key name. Or use oid if prefered.

This works on 9.3 but I think also 9.x.

Answer (score 4):

Simpler and faster by casting to [**`regclass`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-oid.html):

```
SELECT conrelid::regclass::text  AS tbl
     , conname                   AS fk_constraint
     , confrelid::regclass::text AS referenced_tbl
FROM   pg_constraint
WHERE  contype = 'f'
AND    conrelid = 'first_table_name'::regclass  -- table name
-- AND conname = 'fk_name' -- optionally restrict to given FK
ORDER  BY conname;
```

A table name is not necessarily unique. Schema-qualify the table name or rely on the [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777).

Works for *any* version of Postgres this side of the millenium.